# numerical integration - Numerical integration converging too slowly

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to run the following code

```
l = N@Subdivide[-1, 1, 20][[;; -2]] + 1/20;
data = Table[NIntegrate[        
    1/2*r*
     Log[r^2 + (x^2 + y^2) - 2 r*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*Cos[t - ArcTan[x, y]]]
    , {t, 0, 2 Pi }, {r, 0, 1/Sqrt[4 Cos[t]^2 + 25 Sin[t]^2]}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 6], {x, l}, {y, l}];
```

and I am getting the error

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

The $x$ and $y$ are parameters for the integration. Is is possible to get the values of $x$ and $y$ for which I am getting the error?

Comment: `NIntegrate::slwcon` is a warning, not an error. If the integral fails to converge, then it's a hint about what might be the problem. If the integral converges, then it can be ignored. (Of course, numerical methods might mess up, that is, give a result that is erroneous without giving any message about it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define

```
int[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/2*r*Log[
    r^2 + (x^2 + y^2) - 
     2 r*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*Cos[t - ArcTan[x, y]]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 
   1/Sqrt[4 Cos[t]^2 + 25 Sin[t]^2]},Method->"LocalAdaptive" ]
```

`Plot3D` shows a smooth surface without error message.

```
Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Probably case `x=0,y=0` causes the message in your solution grid!

Try

```
Table[{x, y, int[x, y]}, {x, Subdivide[-1, 1, 21]}, {y,Subdivide[-1, 1, 21]}]
```

which evaluates without error message